# Why does VS define a macro for my function?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, macros

I have a member function that returns a reference to a `CString` member of the class. It looks something like this:

```
const CString& GetDateFormat() const { return MyString; }
```

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and whenever I type this function, the IDE automatically changes it to `GetDateFormatA()`. When I go to the function definition and hover over the function name I see this:

```
#define GetDateFormat GetDateFormatA
```

So it's like VS automatically created this macro.

The function works fine but I have already seen this multiple times (I mean a function — written by others — with a macro renaming it by appending an `A`) and I am quite curious and a bit confused. What's the purpose? Is it something related to character encoding or at least to strings?

Comment: The macro was there before you wrote your function.

Comment: So where does this macro get defined?

Comment: @UKMonkey Given the `A` suffix, most likely `<windows.h>` (or a header included from there). It's how Windows differentiates `char`-based and `wchar_t`-based routines.

Comment: @Angew I don't disagree - but no harm in asking ... if it turns out it's in "MyEpicClass.h" and it's auto generated then it's a pretty reasonable question.

Comment: Please post (and google) the exact name of the function. You may find there's a WinAPI function of the same name, which could help you explain the behaviour.

Comment: Is the actual name a closely guarded trade secret?

Comment: @Angew I googled the function name ('GetDateFormat' btw) and there actually is a function with the same name (though not with the same signature). Does this cause any problem? My function is also a member of the 'CDateFormatter' class so it's not just floating in itself. But I guess it would be the best to change the name anyway.

Thank you all!

Comment: @UKMonkey I couldn't find it anywhere explicitly in my project files. So Angew might have a point there, too.

Thank you, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GetDateFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318086(v=vs.85).aspx) is a WinAPI function which takes at least one parameter whose type involves `TCHAR` (in this case, it's the parameters `LPCTSTR lpFormat` and `LPTSTR lpDateStr`). All such WinAPI functions actually exist in two forms: one with an `A` appended, and one with `W` appended. The `A` variant is used when `TCHAR` means `char`, and the `W` one is used when `TCHAR` means `wchar_t`. To support this, `<windows.h>` actually defines a macro for each such function, resolving to one or the other based on whether `_UNICODE` is defined. In your case, there's a definition somewhere in WinAPI headers similar to this:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
# define GetDateFormat GetDateFormatW
#else
# define GetDateFormat GetDateFormatA
#endif
```

This is where your program's occasional reference to `GetDataFormatA` comes from. You can read more about [working with `TCHAR`s on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407(v=vs.85).aspx).

How to solve this depends on whether you need to call WinAPI's `GetDateFormat` and use its `char`/`wchar_t` distinction. If so, you will have to rename your function. However, my impression is that you're not interested in the WinAPI function. In that case, a solution would be to add the following lines to your header which declares your `GetDateFormat`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#undef GetDateFormat
```

That way, nobody consuming your header will see the macro and `GetDateFormat` will remain `GetDateFormat`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the link. :)